# How are configuration settings being loaded for ASP.NET Core on Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have an `appsettings.json` file with some default settings in it, just a localdb SQL Server connection string and some logging settings. I then have an `appsettings.Staging.json` file that contains some seed data for the database, and no Connection String. I do not have an `appsettings.Production.json` file.

When I publish my ASP.NET Core project to Azure, my profile is configured to use an Azure database connection string at runtime as the DefaultConnection. When I publish, an `appsettings.production.json` file is created on the Azure server that contains the Azure SQL connection string as well as the rest of the settings I had in my `appsettings.json` file, however the database is created and seeded based on values that are in my `appsettings.Staging.json` file.

The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable on the server is set to "Staging":

```
> echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%
D:\home\site\wwwroot
Staging
```

When I run my application, it uses the Azure SQL server database, whose connection string only exists in `appsettings.production.json`.

So my question is: Why is the Connection String from the Production config being used when the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is set to Staging? And how can it be clearly using settings from both the Production and Staging config files? ASP.NET Core loads configurations like this:

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

So I don't see how it can be using settings from anything outside of `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Staging.json`.

Comment: Are you sure that the connection string is taken from the production config (you could test that by *changing* the production config), and not from some environment variable? The usual way on Azure is to take these things from environment variables (iirc).

Comment: Hmm, good point. I suppose ASP.NET Core uses environment variables as a configuration provider as well as the json files.

Comment: That was it. I changed the DefaultConnection app setting on the dashboard and the sql connection failed. I was wrong all along about it using the production config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `WebHostBuilder` that is being created with [`CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L152) in ASP.NET Core 2 comes with a lot of good defaults. One of those is the application configuration:

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
    if (appAssembly != null)
    {
        config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
    }
}

config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

if (args != null)
{
    config.AddCommandLine(args);
}
```

So it will first add the `appsettings.json` and the `appsettings.{environmentName}.json` files. Then, if the current environment is a development environment it will also load the user secrets. Then, it will add the environment variables, and finally it will add command line arguments if any were supplied when the application was started.

The way this is set up, environment variables are added to be able to *overwrite* configuration within JSON files. This is especially made so that for production environments, configuration secrets will not be visible within configuration files but can be specified more secretly as environment variables when the process launches.

Especially for Azure, this is usually the way Azure SQL databases are configured. So in your case, it’s very likely that it’s not the production configuration from the JSON files is being read but instead that Azure provides the connection string via an environment variable.

Comment: App settings are provided as environment variables with the same key in Azure App Service. Connection strings use prefixed keys, but the environment variable provider special-cases them: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L83