# Asp.net core 6 app on Azure uses Development environment by default?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, appsettings

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6. On my local machine, it correctly uses my development app settings (the ones from `appsettings.Development.json`) thanks to `launchSettings.json`.

When I publish it on a linux server, it correctly uses my production app settings (the ones from `appsettings.json`).

But when I upload it to Azure, it uses by default the development environment and I am clueless why. I even added `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Production` in Azure, but it is ignored. My only workaround is to remove the `appsettings.Development.json` file from the server...

Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Could the [host defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351206/how-are-configuration-settings-being-loaded-for-asp-net-core-on-azure?rq=1) have changed? Are you using `WebApplicationBuilder.CreateBuilder()` to create the host?

Comment: Yes, program.cs starts with this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By searching ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the solution, I found it to be set to Development in a web.config file. I remember that I tried to run the app locally under IIS but can't remember that I set the variable. I guess it created the file at that time.

So if you are in the same situation, think about the web.config file which could affect the publication to Azure.

**Update**: I made the test. I created an IIS launch config. VS created the web.config file. Then I manually added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the UI. It added it to the web.config file. In the UI, I then removed the env var. Guess what? It didn't remove it from the file...